# coxeter element of a reflection group (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, reflection-groups

I am reading reflection groups and coxeter groups book by Humphreys. now I want to learn more about "coxeter element" of a reflection group. Can any body suggests me some good books to read more about coxeter element.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I like §6 of Bourbaki *Lie groups and Lie algebras*, chap. V.

Comment: Bourbaki is definitely the fundamental reference (though I changed their order of development a lot for expository purposes), and it wouldn't hurt to go back to Coxeter's 1951 paper in Duke J.  There aren't many detailed treatments in textbooks, however.  (If you are looking at Chapter 3 of my book, be sure to check the list of revisions posted on my homepage.  Modern print-on-demand publishing doesn't allow for further corrected reprintings, but some points in my exposition need more precision.)